# FCM notification return get same data second time when it open second notification

Tags: android

I am sending notification using some server code. I know there is different way and technique to handle Background and Foreground notification. Its delivered perfectly in both case. But there is some problem with some extra ordinary case :

**!) Send notification with data to device.**

**2) Receive it from device and open it as per "click_action" mention which activity is open.**

Here is code in android manifest for `click_action`:

```
<activity
        android:name=".activity.VideoNotificationActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:taskAffinity=""
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.DarkStatusBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="VideoDetailsActivity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

So, this activity open successfully as per `click_action : VideoDetailsActivity`

Here is the getting data code for such background condition:

```
val bundle = intent.extras
if (bundle != null) {
    isNotification = true
    mVideoData = Gson().fromJson(bundle.getString(Globals.videoObject), ModelVideoList::class.java) as ModelVideoList
}
```

After that video-data is get and play video successfully. But then after some case:

**3) Minimize the app(I am not going anywhere from this screen. Just touched minimize app button!).**

**4) Send second notification from server with different data! And its received successfully.**

**5) Click that notification and open the same screen but data is of previous video(Means that second notification data which I clicked is not getting hence there is I'm getting old data of previous notification!)**

So, my case is what to do if user minimizes the app of opened notification screen and receive second time notification with different data which is open with same old one data?!

Here, is data which I'm sending:

```
{
"title": "New video added!",
"body": "Tap here to see a video!",
"click_action": "VideoDetailsActivity",
"icon": "ic_notification",
"color": "#CD201F",
"tag": "video_of_the_day",
"sound": "sound.mp3",
"notification_type": "video_of_the_day",
"data": {
    "id": 20,
    "title": "abcd",
    "video": "abcd.mp4",
    "video_webm": "abcd.webm",
    "height": 960,
    "width": 540,
    "thumbnail": "abcd.jpg",
    "created": 4124,
    "created_at": "2019-07-05 11:09:10",
    "updated_at": "2019-12-13 07:17:18",
    "video_url": "video_link",
    "is_new": false
    },
"android_channel_id": "Video"
}
```

Comment: Where do you handle background case ? in onResume ?

Comment: No in `onCreate()` because some layout must be initialize first!

Answer (score 0):

Pass different notification Id while generate the notification

Comment: Where in server code? Is it possible to send `notification_id`?

Comment: onMessageReceived method is called when you generate your notification
These are firebase service which you implement for custom notification's

Comment: `onMessageReceived` is being not called when app in background! See https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-multiple

Comment: There are two types of notification we send 
1. Data Key Notification 
2. Notification Key Notification 

Please say to server guy to send notification on data key in android

With this you get both notification while you are background or foreground